# mysql node js - does not continue to execute the next statements on connection failure and exits the code

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am writing a script where I have to check if i can connect to a mysql db and then print if the connection was success or failure and then continue to execute the script. I am using mysql npm package. When the connection is successful, the script continues, but when the connection fails, the script terminates. How do I make it to continue the eexecution

sample code:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host: host,
                user: user,
                password: dbpassword,               
                port: port

                });


                connection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('DB connection failed inside connection------------------', err)                

                    }else{
                console.log('MySQL DB Server responded to ping');

                    }

                }); 
some other code-----------------
```

if the connection fails, some other code is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mysql which doesn't return a promise. So switching over to mysql2 'const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');' solved my issue as it returns a promise

```html
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
//var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

async function tester()

{
 var testdata = "mysql, localhost, 3307, root, root"
 console.log('testdata------------',testdata)
 console.log('inside tester function')
 
 var mysqldbstat = await dbstatuscheck(testdata)
 
 
 
 if (mysqldbstat == "true")
 {
 console.log('db check passed')
 }else{
  console.log('db check failed')
 }
 
}
 
async function dbstatuscheck(testdata)
{
 
 var testdata = testdata.replace(/ /g, '');
   
 if (testdata.includes(",")) {
        testdata = testdata.split(",")
        if (testdata[0] == "mysql") { 
   var dbhost = testdata[1]
   var dbport = testdata[2]
   var dbuser = testdata[3]
   var dbpassword = testdata[4]   
   console.log('mysql connection string--------------', dbhost, dbport, dbuser, dbpassword)
   } 
        } 
 
 try{
  
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: dbhost,
    port: dbport,
    user: dbuser,
    password: dbpassword});
  
  status ="true"
  console.log('connection established') 
  connection.end()
 
 }catch(err)
  {
  console.log('connection failed------------', err)
  status="false"
  }

 return status   

}

tester()
```